# How to force focus on Digital Crown in SwiftUI TabView on watchOS

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, watchos, swiftui-tabview

I have a tricky use case with vertical TabView in SwiftUI on watchOS.
I display a Map in a Tabview with a button to toggle interaction with the map using Digital Crown to zoom/pan. If I have no interaction with the map, I can move from one tab to another using Digital Crown. If I set interaction to the map for using Digital Crown and then remove it, I can't use the Digital Crown anymore to change the active TabView. I can only do that by a swipe gesture on the screen. I have tried different methods to force focus back to the TabView controller without any success. Do you have any tip or suggestion ?

Here is the sample code:

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isZooming = false
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            // Tab 1
            VStack {
                Text("First tab")
            }
            // Tab 2
            VStack {
                Map(interactionModes: isZooming ? .zoom : [])
                Button {
                    isZooming.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text(isZooming ? "Cancel" : "Zoom")
                }
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.verticalPage)
    }
}
```

Comment: No. I have sent the case to Apple, no response (of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has acknowledged it’s a bug.
The workaround is to set the Map to disabled by adding the following view modifier in this sample case :

> .disabled(isZooming)